# The input field always be a zero after typing sth in and deleting it

Tags: reactjs, antd

[Show in CodeSanbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/practical-pond-161i1?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

I made a validated input field with custom validator of antd-form. However, all is well, except that the input field will always be a zero after typing sth and deleting it. I expected that it would be null, nothing showing in the input field. Code showed as below and above link.
And thank you for reading this question.

```js
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Form, Input } from "antd";
const FormItem = Form.Item;
import "antd/dist/antd.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
    return (
      <Form>
        <FormItem
          label="Number in Stock"
          labelCol={{ span: 5 }}
          wrapperCol={{ span: 12 }}
        >
          {getFieldDecorator("stock", {
            getValueFromEvent: e => {
              const convertedValue = Number(e.currentTarget.value);
              if (isNaN(convertedValue)) {
                return e.currentTarget.value;
              } else {
                return convertedValue;
              }
            },
            rules: [
              {
                validator: (rule, value, callback) => {
                  const number = Number(value);
                  if (!value && value !== 0) {
                    callback("required");
                  } else if (!Number.isInteger(number)) {
                    callback("The number should be an integer");
                  } else if (number < 0 || number > 100) {
                    callback("between 0 and 100");
                  } else {
                    callback();
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            validateFirst: true
          })(<Input />)}
        </FormItem>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}

const WrappedApp = Form.create()(App);

ReactDOM.render(<WrappedApp />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lies in the `getValueFromEvent` function. When the value you get is falsy (in this case an empty string), converting it to a number will evaluate to `0`.

You might want to do something like this:

```
getValueFromEvent: e => {
    if (!e.currentTarget.value){
        return e.currentTarget.value;
    }

    const convertedValue = Number(e.currentTarget.value);
    if (isNaN(convertedValue)) {
        return e.currentTarget.value;
    } else {
        return convertedValue;
    }
},
```